# Failed Update data by using a TableAdapter in .NET Framework applications

Tags: vb.net

In Visual studio 2022, I have created a VB forms connect with my table in SQL.
I can add new record in table but not update. Here is the code

```
Private Sub ButtonUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonUpdate.Click 
     Try 
         Me.Validate() 
         Me.EmployeeBindingSource.EndEdit() 
         Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.Update(Me.HRDataSet.Employee) 
         MsgBox("Update successful") 
     Catch ex As Exception 
         MsgBox("Update failed") 
     End Try 
 End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: MsgBox("Update failed") and won't update

Comment: The message you have in the exception handler isn't helpful to anyone, including yourself. Remove the `Try-Catch` block so that you can see the error message. You may also consider reading more about exception handling.

Comment: Or run under the debugger, put a breakpoint on the `MsgBox` call, and see what the contents of `ex` are when that happens.  (At a bare minimum, anything diagnostic in an exception handler should report the exception message, and the use of the message box (barely) qualifies for that here.)

Comment: If your issue is resolved, please add an answer and accept it (if you have the rep to do so) so that we can see that you don't need any more help without opening the question and reading it and all the comments.

Comment: If a table adapter doesn't have an `UpdateCommand` set, it is generally because the corresponding database table doesn't have a primary key. In order to generate an `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand`, each record must be able to be uniquely identified, which is what the PK is for.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I found the issue. Forget to update query. Thank you all.